# unittest python, missing function test

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7

I'm learning about unittesting and I'm finding that not all of the test functions are being run. I've found that the first four run perfectly but the last two give no results. If I comment out the first four functions the last two will show up. How can I get all of the functions to test?

I'm new to unit-testing so any advice is well received

```
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_country(self):
        self.assertTrue(country in x)
    def test_company_size(self):
        self.assertTrue(company_size in x)
    def test_zipcode(self):
        self.assertTrue(zipcode in x)
    def test_region(self):
        self.assertTrue(region in x) 
    def test_street(self):
        self.assertTrue(street in x)  
    def test_address(self):
        self.assertTrue(address in x)  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(MyTest)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=3).run(suite)
```

RESULTS:

```
test_company_size (__main__.MyTest) ... ok
test_country (__main__.MyTest) ... ok
test_region (__main__.MyTest) ... ok
test_zipcode (__main__.MyTest) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.000s

OK
[Finished in 1.5s]
```

Comment: Do you perhaps have an indentation error, so that some functions are inside another?

Comment: that's it, I just fixed it. Thank you!